# is this proof that if $ B $ is infinite correct

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given A is an infinite set and $A \subseteq B $ prove that B is infinite, Ok so there exists  $ f:A\to A\ $ that is one to one but not onto by definition of an infinite set. to prove that $B$ is infinite i have to prove that there exists a function $ g:B\to B\ $ that is one to one and not onto and define it somehow, so here is how i started, I noticed that since $A \subseteq B $ then $ f:A\to A\ $ can be expressed as $ f:A\to B\ $ then i defined $ h:B\to A\ $ as a one to one function and defined $ g:B\to B\ $ to be the the composition of $ f $ with $ h $ , then since $ h $ is one to one and $ f $ is one to one then $ g $ is one to one and since $ f $ is not onto then $ g $ is not onto, now since i have defined a function $ g:B\to B\ $ that is one to one and not onto then $ B $ is infinite.
Sorry if i have a bad proof writing style but im only 16 years old and im not that good at proofs

Comment: the proof writing book that im using states :

Comment: the proof writing book that im using states : a set $ A  $ is infinite if there exists a function $ f:A\to A\ $ that is one to one but not onto

Comment: You can't have injective $h:B\rightarrow A$ in general.

Comment: couldnt i define $ h $ anyway i want?

Answer (score 1):

Just define $g(x) = f(x)$ if $x \in A$ and $g(x) = x$ otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

That $ A \subset B$ means that the function
$$
  i \colon  A \ni x \mapsto  x \in B
$$
is defined, and clearly one-to-one. (it could be onto if $A=B$, othetrwise not. 
As you have said, that $A$ is infinite means that there exist a function
$$
   f \colon A \rightarrow A
$$ 
which is one-to-one but not onto. Now see at the composition $ i \circ f \colon  A \rightarrow B$ which is clearly one-to-one (all compositions of one-to-one functions will be one-to-one) but not onto, which yiellds the result.